# Laravel mix not producing version files in manifest

Tags: laravel-mix, gulp-sourcemaps

I'm working on `Laravel` and `Vuejs` project. In this project when I run command `npm run watch`, it's not generating version file in `manifest`. How can I solve the issue?

My development environment is:

1. Laravel 5.6.*
2. Laravel-mix: "^4.1.4"
3. Node v11.5.0
4. Npm 6.11.3

Answer (score 0):

Just able to solved the problem. In previous version of "laravel-mix": "^0.10.0", I have written in webpack.mix.js Like:

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js').version();

But in "laravel-mix": "^4.1.4" need to write Like:

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js').sourceMaps().version(); and this one is working good.